# How to implement a multi-row timeline with dragable items in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a timeline grid similar to this one: https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/timeline/month-view#drag-drop=true&themeVariant=light

The goal is to have a timeline along the x-axis, and a scalable amount of rows along the y-axis (basically a regular calendar week-view, but with non-fixed amount of days). I want to be able to drag and drop items on a fine-grained level along the x-axis (with minute precision), as well as drag and drop them to new rows. How can this be achieved in Angular?

I've tried to come up with a solution using [Angular Material's Drag and Drop feature](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview), but can't really figure out how I would represent the finely grained x-axis, without creating a long list with items representing every minute of the day. Is this a viable technique, or are there simpler ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been creating a [similar component](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/scheduler) lately, but I haven't implemented the timeline mode yet. A demo can be found [here](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/scheduler).

What I did is

Keep the resource groups in a `BehaviorSubject`

```
resources$ = new BehaviorSubject<(Resource | ResourceGroup)[]>([]);
```

Interfaces:

```
export interface ResourceGroup {
    description: string;
    children: (ResourceGroup | Resource)[];
}

export interface Resource {
    description: string;
    events: SchedulerEvent[];
}

export interface SchedulerEvent {
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    color: string;
    description: string;
}
```

The events are a mapping of the Resources->EventGroups:

```
this.events$ = this.resources$
  .pipe(map((resourcesOrGroups) => resourcesOrGroups.map(resOrGroup => this.getResourcesForGroup(resOrGroup))))
  .pipe(map(jaggedResources => jaggedResources.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), [])))
  .pipe(map(resources => resources.map(res => res.events)))
  .pipe(map(jaggedEvents => jaggedEvents.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), [])));
```

Then you need to split these events into parts (for the calendar mode, timeline mode will be splitting per week/month) per day basis:

```
this.eventParts$ = this.events$.pipe(
  map((events) =>  events.map((ev) => this.timelineService.splitInParts(ev)))
);
```

This is the code which splits an event into parts per day:

```
export class BsTimelineService {

  public splitInParts(event: SchedulerEvent | PreviewEvent) {
    let startTime = event.start;
    const result: SchedulerEventPart[] = [];
    const eventOrNull = 'color' in event ? event : null;
    while (!this.dateEquals(startTime, event.end)) {
      const end = new Date(startTime.getFullYear(), startTime.getMonth(), startTime.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0);
      result.push({ start: startTime, end: end, event: eventOrNull });
      startTime = end;
    }
    if (startTime != event.end) {
      result.push({ start: startTime, end: event.end, event: eventOrNull });
    }

    return <SchedulerEventWithParts>{ event: event, parts: result };
  }
  
  private dateEquals(date1: Date, date2: Date) {
    return (
      date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
      date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
      date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
    );
  }

}
```

Interfaces:

```
export interface SchedulerEventWithParts {
    event: SchedulerEvent;
    parts: SchedulerEventPart[];
}
```

And at last you can filter out only the event parts for this week:

```
this.eventPartsForThisWeek$ = combineLatest([
  this.daysOfWeekWithTimestamps$,
  this.eventParts$
    .pipe(map(eventParts => eventParts.map(evp => evp.parts)))
    .pipe(map(jaggedParts =>  jaggedParts.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), [])))
  ])
  .pipe(map(([startAndEnd, eventParts]) => {
    return eventParts.filter(eventPart => {
      return !((eventPart.end.getTime() <= startAndEnd.start) || (eventPart.start.getTime() >= startAndEnd.end));
    });
  }));
```

Which you can render in your view using the `async` pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let eventPart of (eventPartsForThisWeek$ | async)"></div>
```

In your case you'll be fine with this, however when you want a calendar mode (like the one I started with) you'll still need to display these events in multiple columns. Therefor I created another observable:

```
this.timelinedEventPartsForThisWeek$ = this.eventPartsForThisWeek$
  .pipe(map(eventParts => {
    // We'll only use the events for this week
    const events = eventParts.map(ep => ep.event)
      .filter((e, i, list) => list.indexOf(e) === i)
      .filter((e) => !!e)
      .map((e) => <SchedulerEvent>e);
    const timeline = this.timelineService.getTimeline(events);

    const result = timeline.map(track => track.events.map(ev => ({ event: ev, index: track.index })))
      .reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), [])
      .map((evi) => eventParts.filter(p => p.event === evi.event).map(p => ({ part: p, index: evi.index })))
      .reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), []);

    return {
      total: timeline.length,
      parts: result
    };
  }));
```

The following method is creating a timeline with tracks for the given events:

```
public getTimeline(events: SchedulerEvent[]) {
    const timestamps = this.getTimestamps(events);
    const tracks: TimelineTrack[] = [];

    timestamps.forEach((timestamp, tIndex) => {
        const starting = events.filter((e) => e.start === timestamp);
        // const ending = events.filter((e) => e.end === timestamp);

        starting.forEach((startedEvent, eIndex) => {
            const freeTracks = tracks.filter(t => this.trackIsFreeAt(t, startedEvent));
            if (freeTracks.length === 0) {
                tracks.push({ index: tracks.length, events: [startedEvent] });
            } else {
                freeTracks[0].events.push(startedEvent);
            }
        });
    });

    return tracks;
}

private getTimestamps(events: SchedulerEvent[]) {
    const allTimestamps = events.map(e => [e.start, e.end])
        .reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), []);

    return allTimestamps
        .filter((t, i) => allTimestamps.indexOf(t) === i)
        .sort((t1, t2) => <any>t1 - <any>t2);
}

private trackIsFreeAt(track: TimelineTrack, event: SchedulerEvent) {
    if (track.events.every((ev) => (ev.end <= event.start) || (event.end <= ev.start))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that I had to omit the `TimelineService` for events created by dragging-dropping, or events being moved around. This causes too much computations through the `TimelineService` and is too intense for a webbrowser to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've had a quick look at the source code and demo as well. Just to clarify, the scheduler's events in the demo are draggable in increments of 30minutes. Is it too intense for the browser to use finer precision, in intervals of one or five minutes?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. The only performance/crashing problem I experienced was when the events are being dragged around. If you're dragging the actual event around, the Timeline computation (which puts the events in seperate tracks) is too intense and is triggered like constantly. This is why I used the `previewEvent$`, which leaves the original event at its position, and the preview is always 100% wide